# Configure Trinket M0 as I2C peripheral

Tags: i2c, adafruit, xbee

I am trying to use I2C to communicate between my XBee3 (controller) and an adafruit trinket m0 (peripheral). I'm pretty confident I have the modules connected properly (trinket SCL/pin 2 to xbee SCL/pin DIO1 & trinket SDA/pin 0 to xbee SDA/pin DIO11, and both grounds are connected). Here is my arduino code on the trinket:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
Wire.begin(72); // join i2c bus
Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output
Serial.print("Waiting for data...");
}

void loop()
{
delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
(void)howMany; // avoid compiler warning about unused parameter

while(1 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
{
char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
Serial.print(c); // print the character
}
int x = Wire.read(); // receive byte as an integer
Serial.println(x); // print the integer
}
```

and here is my code on the XBee:

```
from machine import I2C

# Instantiate an I2C peripheral.
i2c = I2C(1)
slave_addr = 72
i2c.writeto(slave_addr, b'123', False)
```

Additionally, when I run an i2c.scan() on the xbee with an ISM330DHCX connected to the xbee's I2C, the address pops right up. But when I use the exact same code with the xbee connected to the trinket m0, the xbee cannot find any devices. (Code pasted below)

```
from machine import I2C

# Instantiate an I2C peripheral.
i2c = I2C(1)

# Scan for I2C slaves connected to the interface and print their address.
for address in i2c.scan():
    print("- I2C device found at address: %s" % hex(address))
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong with configuring the trinket m0 to be an i2c peripheral? Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm trying to communicate with I2C between two Trinket M0 and am facing the same issue.

Comment: I never solved it. After some additional research, I figured that the trinket M0 couldn't be configured as a peripheral. I ended up using a different microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

I have two Adafruit Trinket M0 arduino boards running on my bench right now talking to each other over I2C. The trick is that you need to install a pull-up resistor between SDA and +3V, and another one between SCL and +3V. Typically it is the peripheral boards that come with those but when you talk between two microcontrollers which are often used as the master controller themselves they are open drain or not powerful enough to drive the bus. Any resistor between 4.7k and 10k ohms should do.

see the following reference doc:

`https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/wire-i2c/pull-up-resistors-i2c/`

From the other direction if you have many peripheral boards that all include their own pull up resistors, the combined resistance on the bus may low enough leak enough current to raise "low" state above 0.4v, at which point communication may have errors.

Or if the wires are too long or there are too many devices without enough pull up resistance (thus too much inherent capacitance) it will take too long for the data lines to reach the "high" state, and you will have to slow down the clock rate or add a signal booster like the LTC4311 (e.g. Adafruit product #4756) to get stable results.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks for posting.  I have moved on in this project, so I'm unable to check to see if it solves the problem.  Nevertheless, this is great information for anyone who may be experiencing similar issues.